# How do we iterate through an object with the keys of the object from API matching with that of the keys defined in translation file in Vue?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I have an object

```
var data= { "Date": "01-01-2024", "Code": "5000", "region": "NA" }
```

(This data is fetched from an API)

and a translation file en.json (vue-i18n for language translation)

en.json:

```json
    {"info": {
        "Code": "CODE",
        "Date": "DATE",
        "region": "REGION"
      }}
```

I'm trying to display the data in a v-list

```html
    <v-list  v-for="(value, key) in data" :key="key">
    <v-list-item>
         <v-list-item-content>
              <v-row>
                  <v-col>
                     {{ $t(`info.$key`) }}
                   </v-col>
                   <v-col>
                     {{ value }}
                    </v-col>
               </v-row>
           </v-list-item-content>
      </v-list-item>

      </v-list>
```

This is the code which I tried.
I'm expecting output like

```
DATE    01-01-2024
CODE    5000
REGION  NA
```

But I'm getting

```
info.$key  01-01-2024
info.$key 5000
info.$key NA
```

And I have a warning in console which says "Not found 'info.key' key in 'en' locale messages."

Can someone help with what's wrong here?

Comment: Just like JS, we don't have a clue what info is..

Comment: @Wimanicesir info is an object inside json file. This json file is used for language translation

Comment: There's no such thing as a "JSON object". JSON is a text format. You serialize objects to JSON and from JSON. When you do that, the objects exist in the language you deserialize them in (in this case, JavaScript, so you have a JavaScript object). If you were to deserliaze that same JSON in C#, it would be a C# object.

Comment: ```{{ $t(`info.$key`) }}``` says "run the `$t` function on the literal string `'info.$key'`". If you want to run `$t` on the **value** of `info.$key`, remove the quotes/tick marks around `info.$key`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Tried {{ $t(info.$key) }}. Getting error "DashboardPage.vue?t=1711642016081:310 TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$key')"

Comment: It should be `{{ $t(\`info.${key}\`) }}`, see [string interpolation in template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation)